# How to remove some bits of code and turn it to a variable using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
CreateDynamicObject(2780, 33.62956, 2237.92529, 180.54372, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
```

I want to know how can I parse the above line to get the values in variables as shown below:

```php
$id = 2780;
$xPos = 33.62956;
$yPos = 2237.92529;
$zPos = 180.54372;
$rxpos= 0.0000;
$rypos = 0.00000;
$rzpos = 0.00000;
```

Since I would like to input a lot of lines like that and save it to an MySQL database.

Comment: Not sure I've ever before encountered this particular pronunciation of "MySQL"! Nice.

Comment: So, you are trying to parse this file or something??  Is this just a text file that looks like this?  A regex might be a good fit here.

Comment: How is your code MySQL or PHP?

Comment: It's neither, I just wanted you guys to tell me how I would remove the bits of codes like CreateDynamicObject into object id and stuff  by using php , and then inserting the object id and stuff to the database. I couldn't post this as a normal text because it detects it as a code

Comment: @user3849771: So this is just a text file?  Is what you've shown the *exact* format?

Comment: @user3849771: P.S. You can use "language hints" to tell the syntax highlighter how to format it.  I added `<!-- language: lang-none -->` to tell it to not format it.  Info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: All I want to do is input a bunch of lines like that, and let php remove the bits of codes into different parts and insert into database.

Comment: @user3849771: Are you just inputting `CreateDynamicObject(...)` lines?  Or is the `Object id = ...` part of the file, too?

Comment: only createdynamicobject, i'm just explaining how I want the variables.

Comment: @user3849771: Ok, that was a little confusing.  I thought it was part of the input.

Comment: So how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  One is just using basic string manipulation.  If you remove the `CreateDynamicObject(` and `);`, then you're left with a comma-separated list.  Use `explode()` on it.

```
$str = 'CreateDynamicObject(2780, 33.62956, 2237.92529, 180.54372, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);';
$str = str_replace(array('CreateDynamicObject(', ');'), '', $str);

list($id, $xPos, $yPos, $zPos, $rxpos, $rypos, $rzpos) = explode(', ', $str);
```

If you have multiple, you can then just create an array to house all the values.

```
$strs = array(
    'CreateDynamicObject(2780, 33.62956, 2237.92529, 180.54372, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);',
    'CreateDynamicObject(2780, 33.62956, 2237.92529, 180.54372, 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);'
);
$vals = array();

foreach($strs as $str){
    $str = str_replace(array('CreateDynamicObject(', ');'), '', $str);
    $row = array();
    list(
        $row['id'], $row['xPos'], $row['yPos'], $row['zPos'], $row['rxpos'], $row['rypos'], $row['rzpos']
    ) = explode(', ', $str);
    $vals[] = $row;
}

var_dump($vals);
```

Comment: Can I like add 4-5 lines of CreateDynamicObject and then save into database, one by one? I know how to make a user input where I can get all the data.

Comment: @user3849771, how are you inputing the lines, you can just loop through the list and store the values in arrays $id[i] $xpos[i] etc.

Comment: @user3849771: This was just an example.  `explode(', ', $str)` just makes it an array, so you can use its values as you wish.  You can loop over your inputs, do this code, then do `$idArray[] = $id` or something.

Comment: Can you guys show me an example of 2 lines. I'm a beginner in PHP/

Comment: @user3849771: How are you getting the input?  Where is it coming from?  Is it just a text field with multiple lines?

Comment: I'v decided not to get the input, rather just put the code in the script and run it.

Comment: @user3849771: Take a look at the 2nd example in my answer.

Comment: No idea, wasn't me. Anyways thanks for your help, and btw how do like print row 1 ID and row 2 ID separately?

Comment: @RocketHazmat : Could you help me like output each row's ID one by one?

Comment: Something like `foreach($vals as $row){ echo $row['id']; }`